# How do extra spells for wizard specialization work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard

I was working up a wizard specializing in illusion for a buddy and ran into a conundrum. You get additional spells for specializing, and this reads as:

> One additional spell from the wizard's specialty school per **spell level** each day.

Does this mean they can cast:

- a single additional illusion spell of level 1,
- two additional illusion spells of level 2,
- three additional illusion spells of level 3,
- (..)
- nine additional illusion spells of level 9

That seems a bit "top heavy" to me. How many extra spells does the wizard get to cast?

Comment: It would only have the effect you claim if it said something like “*Each spell level gains* one additional spell from the wizard’s specialty school per spell level each day.”

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The wizards gets to cast a single extra spell of each spell level:**

- a single additional illusion spell of level 1,
- a single additional illusion spell of level 2,
- a single additional illusion spell of level 3,
- (..)
- a single additional illusion spell of level 9

While the wording may be ambiguous enough to allow both interpretations I believe the correct is the one described in this answer because the alternative would be rather ridiculous.

Further, here's an official [evoker](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20070430a&page=5) and an official [diviner](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/cc/20030927a&page=3). They use the rules as described above rather than, for example, getting increasingly bigger piles of higher-level spells.